# Wordpres posts aren't loading on mobile version

Tags: wordpress, mobile

Posts aren't loading on website al9anat.com when accessing it on mobile

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please post some relevant code, console errors maybe or other context not all users are willing to go to external unverified links...

Answer (score 0):

There is this part of CSS that makes the whole page invisible. Please note that it’s invisible on both big and small screen devices, so I guess the reason you only see the problem on mobile could be that the browser on your big screen device is showing the cached version.

Comment: I didn't understand.. the page it's showing but it block on loading more articles